# How can I not give up on writing my story?

Tags: creative-writing

I am planning a book, but I can't convey it into words. I am stalling, planning unimportant things that won't be essential to my novel.

I have given up on over twenty drafts, thinking one idea was better than another but I feel a sense of doubt (because of all the hype on books that have a better plot and characters than mine), and I feel like my novel isn't worth writing anymore. I feel like I have failed. I feel like my novel's never going to sprout.

What do I do?

Comment: "I have given up on over twenty drafts" - are these completed drafts, or incomplete versions that you "gave up on" partway through?

Comment: These are incomplete versions that I gave up on @F1Krazy

Comment: Can you explain what 'planning a book…' means if you 'can't convey it into words'? Can you say where you got the inspiration for any of those drafts, how they differed and what was wrong with any of them?

Can you say what '… all the hype on books that have a better plot and characters…' means?

Can you say anything about what your book might deal with?

Comment: Is 'I plan a book…' solely in your head, or have you yet written on outline… a 'plan', to go way before any draft?

Why be 'intimidated' by praise for the work of other writers? The more so if they're praised only for their plots and characters; not their writing?

Can you separate story from plan from plot from draft, go back and explain how your 'stories' as such could not be good enough?

You find more detailed help somewhere like Quora where extended discussion is normal.

Either way, why not join a book club or two, where ordinary readers critique anything in print?

Answer (score 3):

Most writers don't just start writing one day and create their magnum opus. They get better with time. Pick up your favorite author's first book and the latest, and you should be able to tell the difference. They get better at everything from plot pacing, to characters, to even sentence construction!

Everyone has to start somewhere. And usually they start at level zero. You can learn a lot about characters and plotting by studying the world around you, but the only way you can really make it better is to write the characters acting the plot.

So just do it. Set aside your doubts, put on some good music and write. Don't stop until you have a first draft, no matter how horrible it is! Then set it aside and work on something else. After a month or, so, you can come back to the first draft. You might get discouraged because you think it's horrible, but that's good. The only way you can tell writing is bad is if you can write something better than that. Try to fix what you can and when you think it's perfect go write something else or watch some videos on writing. After another two months, go back to that first project (or another story). Read it. Fix it. Repeat.

Eventually you'll have a book that when you publish it will generate all the hype.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an experiment you can try.

Put the outline aside and completely ignore it. Pretend it doesn't exist. Open up a blank document (or a blank notebook) and start writing, fresh from the beginning from memory alone. See where it takes you.

I'm suggesting this as someone who discovered they were a pantser, someone who writes better without using an outline, by doing this exact thing. I kept doing outlines and would start writing but never get anywhere. I never got around to actually properly writing until I put the outlines aside and just let the words flow naturally.

Forget what other people's works are like. Forget how bad it may look at first. The first draft is supposed to be bad. You make it better by editing it later on.

And one more thing: no novel idea is 100% original.

You're always gonna have bits and pieces that are similar to someone else's works and that's okay. Your novel can even have the exact same premise as someone else's. That's okay too. What matters is how you approach it. No one else can write that novel exactly like you can.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be stuck in drafting or outlining your novel.

Yes, you can outline yourself into oblivion, so your first step is to let go of the outlining after a while. One way to do this might be to use [the Snowflake Method](https://www.advancedfictionwriting.com/articles/snowflake-method/), but you might find other methods that work for you as well.

What you're looking for is a limited amount of work/time from first idea to starting to write the first draft.

Some people call this: just write the damn thing...

And yes, it's also fully valid to throw all outlining out the window and get to the drafting at once. (Writing the novel by the seats of your pants, so called).

You'll have to figure out what works for you, so some experimentation will likely be needed to figure out how much outlining you need before you can write the first draft.

Your second step is to realize that for 99% of all authors (intolerable geniuses excluded) "the first draft of anything is shit" ([Hemingway said so](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/09/20/draft/), so you're in good company).

What this means is that no one gets it right on the first try. Creativity, and creative writing, doesn't work like that. It works by writing several drafts, cutting out, adding in, polishing and throwing away.

It's also worth mentioning that your outline will likely be pathetic compared to your final novel, and that's obviously ok, since no one will want to read your outline anyway. You don't need a perfect outline or a perfect first draft to produce... well no book is perfect, but most of them are way better than the first draft and especially the outline...

James Scott Bell says (in "Revision and Self Editing for Publication") that you should write the first draft hot (with passion and heart) and then edit it cold (with calculation and brains).

You write a crappy first draft, then you edit it into the perfection you see in other works (after you've mastered drafting AND editing), but never worry too much about the first draft...

...maybe think of the first draft as a cast net, you don't know what you'll get until you've hauled it in again... or a planted seed, that may grow into a beautiful tree with a lot of time and hard work, or maybe it's just weed...

Answer (score 1):

The first step here is to sit down and read through the twenty drafts.

Quickly.  In an afternoon or so.  The point is to have them fresh in your mind *together*.  If there is a problem with the drafts it will leap out at you as a common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I fear those that are familiar with my answers here will grow tired of me saying this, but:

**Write the next novel.**

If you still feel that your book doesn't meet your standards after twenty drafts, it may be that you either lack the skills to make it work or the distance to understand what needs to be done.

In both cases you will profit from putting your present work away for the moment and focussing on something else. If you lack skill, writing the next novel (and the next and the next) will better increase your ability than endlessly polishing a failed attempt. And if you lack distance, half a year or more of thinking about another project will clear your mind and allow you to recognize the shortcomings of the project you had put aside and give you fresh ideas on how to solve them.

There are some well-known anecdotes about famous writers who have rewritten a certain masterpiece multiple times – apparently Hemingway rewrote the ending for *A Farewell to Arms* thirtynine times – but if you are an aspiring writer it can be detrimental to your development if you don't allow yourself to move on from what is potentially a failure. [Most debut novels aren't the first novels their writers have written.](https://medium.com/@Ava_Jae/how-many-books-did-you-write-before-you-published-your-debut-6711d7e73c92) And you can always come back to every abandoned work anytime you feel that you are now ready for it. They aren't lost.